# highcharts gauge chart height taking extra space

Tags: charts, highcharts

I want the gauge chart inside a 'rectangular' div, with height=300px and width =400px

If I setup the chart height=300, width=400,the resulting chart is not taking all the available height&width (see image), in fact it looks as if it is taking the necessary space for a circle instead of a semi-circle. 
[image]

I set up height=300, width=400 for all internal pies, as well as these parameters in 'chart', with no improvements

```
            spacingTop: 0,
            spacingBottom: 0,
            spacingLeft: 0,
            spacingRight: 0,
             plotBorderWidth: null,
            margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
          spacing: [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

jsfiddle available here https://jsfiddle.net/perikut/0woz42vt/248/
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the space is adapted for a circle - please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2jrch4xn/

You need to position the chart as you want by `center` property:

```
pane: {
  ...,
  center: ['50%', '100%']
},

plotOptions: {
  series: {
    ...,
    center: ['50%', '115%']
  },
  ...
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4m2t6p35/1/